# Is "Obtuse" related to "Dull"?

Tags: etymology

I'm imagining a knife. Not very sharp = dull, right? Is that the origin of the use of "obtuse" to mean "not very bright"?

Comment: _Obtuse_ **means** 'dull', physically; it comes from the Latin verb _obtundere_, which means 'to beat against' something, i.e, to dull it. _Dull_ itself, however, has a different etymology, coming through Proto-Germanic _*dul-_, ablaut-form of _*dwel-_ 'to be foolish', and ultimately to P.I.E. _*dheu¹-_, which refers to a number of things, including "defective perception or wits". So _dull_ is not only unrelated to _obtuse_ etymologically; it turns out that the physical meaning 'not sharp' is derived from the original meaning 'stupid'. Some metaphors are older than I thought.

Comment: Your explanation is great, @JohnLawler, you should put this into an answer.

Comment: Yes, fascinating answer, I'd love to "accept" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English has long associated terms for **wit** and **weapons,** beginning with [*sharp*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sharp) in Old English:

> Old English *scearp* “having a cutting edge; pointed; intellectually acute, active, shrewd; keen (of senses); severe; biting, bitter (of tastes),” from Proto-Germanic **skarpaz,* literally “cutting”. . . . The figurative meaning “acute or penetrating in intellect or perception” was in Old English. . . .

It appears that a similar figurative usage influenced the meaning of [*obtuse*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=obtuse) (both in English and its source languages):

> early 15c., “dull, blunted,” from Middle French *obtus* (fem. *obtuse*), from Latin *obtusus* “blunted, dull,” also used figuratively. . . . Sense of “stupid” is first found c.1500.

Conversely, [*dull*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=dull) “stupid” (from Old English *dol* “dull-witted, foolish”), [*blunt*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=blunt) (perhaps related to *blunder*), and [*keen*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=keen) “clever, wise” (from Proto-Germanic **kan-*) developed in the other direction, referring first to wits c.1200 and later becoming associated with weapons and tools in the 13–14c.

Thus, while these words are unrelated etymologically, the wit/weapon metaphor has influenced them all to describe both physical and mental edges in English.

Answer (score 0):

I note in usage that obtuse tends toward the meaning of "(intentionally) stupid", as in the admonishing "Don't be obtuse!" (when someone is obviously, obstinately, pretending ignorance.)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. You might improve your answer by citing references. And do you see ways in which the word "dull" is related to "obtuse"?